# docker -d vs. service docker start

Tags: docker

I've installed docker on a VirtualBox running Fedora 20. I've been having problems getting hello-world to work, and eventually discovered that I can successfully run docker run hello-world only if I start docker on the command line with /usr/bin/docker -d.  If I start docker with service docker start, any docker run command I try just hangs.

Why does service docker start not start docker in daemon mode, and how do I set up the other_args in /etc/sysconfig/docker to get it to do so?

Comment: have you installed docker following the official instructions for fedora? https://docs.docker.com/installation/fedora/

Comment: Can you check the contents of /etc/default/docker (probably /lib/systemd/system/docker.service in fedora) - perhaps some undesired options for the docker daemon have been specified in there and that's the culprit.

Comment: installed as specified in the official instructions.

Comment: /etc/default/docker and/or /lib/systemd/system/docker don't exist, so no contents specified there

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is just to remove docker and reinstall:

```
dnf remove docker
dnf install docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. I removed docker, installed the latest version of virtualbox and the guest additions, upgraded Fedora 20 to 22, recreated loop devices because they got lost in the upgrade, rebooted countless times, and now service docker start starts up a version that docker run hello-world can run against successfully. It only took 2 days :-(